# sensitive sink as php vulnerability?

Tags: php, security

I'm scanning a folder in my server using RIPS. The report came out and some of the vulnerabilities that were reported are "Userinput reaches sensitive sink.". The lines reported are lines defining a variable. You can see the report [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9bE9.jpg). Does anyone know how I can fix this? Shouldnt this be normal and not reported as a vulnerability?

Comment: Such a scanner is bound to give false-positives ([googling gives this for example](http://sourceforge.net/p/rips-scanner/discussion/1150342/thread/1b3e0f83/)). "Userinput reaches sensitive sink" seems to mean: "RIPS believes that variable X can contain user input. At this point in the code the userinput in X could possibly exploited." Check and double-check where each of the variables in the corresponding line is defined, and follow their trail through your program. I suppose it could give the same message if the program is unable to find out where a variable is defined.

Comment: Consider the case where you have code as follows:

Answer (score 2):

Most of them look like false alarms, since there is no actual user input involved. Most include paths are constructed from a function which probably gets its data from a db or a config file.

`get_locale()` could be problematic, if it takes the `Accept-Language` header of HTTP requests and uses them un-sanitized.

Comment: anyone can provide a better answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can get details of all the sensitive sinks here:

```
http://awap.sourceforge.net/support.html#sanitization
```

Which do have all sensitive sinks for PHP language and how to mitigate those vulnerabilities.

You can read a research paper regarding this here:

```
http://awap.sourceforge.net/papers/wap_dsn2016.pdf
http://awap.sourceforge.net/papers/WAP_IEEE_TR_Mar2016.pdf
```

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where you have a code as follows:

```
$name = $city = $email = $message = "";
```

RIPS reports this code as User inputs reach sensitive sinks.

To solve this you can apply the following trick:

```
$name=test_input("");
$city=test_input("");
$email=test_input("");
$message=test_input("");

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripcslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data =  htmlentities($data,  ENT_QUOTES,  "utf-8");
    return $data;
}
```